# Padding changing the size of a div with box-sizing on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, width, padding

I am trying to add a padding to an element inside a DIV. My problem is that it add this padding to the total size of my DIV.

I try to stop this with the following code in my div:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
ms-box-sizing: border-box;
webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

It works fine on Chrome but I still have the problem on Firefox. I can't understand why.

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: please add a http://jsfiddle.net/ or code..

Comment: You're missing a hyphen before `moz` and all of the other prefixes e.g. `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: if Adrift's comment doesn't fix it, what version of firefox are you using?

Comment: Adrift, thanks a lot it worked fine!

Comment: Also, you don't need the `-ms-` prefix for IE; the only version it knows is plain `box-sizing`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra padding to the width of a div:

```
div {
    // In this example total div width is 120px
    // box-sizing: content-box is the default style. No need to specify it.
    width: 100px
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Or if you want to make the padding part of the total div width:

```
div { 
    // In this example total div width is 100px
    // support Firefox, WebKit, Opera and IE8+
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; //always place the standard declaration last, so it overwrites browser specific ones in case they get deprecated  
    width: 100px
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```